# Problems with case-when-value-between something -formula

Tags: sql, case-when

I have a case in where I have product codes, which are 4 symbol long. Then in some cases products are basically same no mather of the first symbol, for example one product code would be 7456 and another 8456 and these products would still have same function. So only difference is the first symbol and three symbols from rigth remains same.

My problem is that I would like to compare two data table with each other and in the first table could be used code 7456 and in the second one code 8456. I would like to mach these two data together but I dunno know how to tell for SQL that if code start with 7 or 8 use three last symbols.

I think that possible solution would be some kind of case when value between 7000-8999 then use 3 right, but I can't get this code to work? Would someone has a solution for me??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
CASE
    WHEN value BETWEEN '7000' AND '8999'
        THEN RIGHT(value, 3)
    ELSE value
END
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! I think this was what I i am looking for, but this doesn't work yet. Now I don't get any errors anymore, but now I got empty cells when value is between 7000 and 8999. I do something wrong?

Comment: Please show the select statement you currectly have and the table schema you wish to select from.

Comment: CASE WHEN value BETWEEN '7000' AND '8999' THEN RIGHT(value, 3) ELSE value END

Comment: No no no. In your question, show us the SQL Statement (the full select) and what the tables look like that you wish to select from (are the columns ints, varchars, datetimes, etc)...

Comment: I was thinking that could the possible problem be that the actual code would be more than 4 symbol long? I meant that if there would some "empty" symbols? If the problem was this what should I type there that sql would understand to use only real symbols?

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working! The problem was like was quessing. Value field was actually 25 symbols long, so there was 21 empty symbols after my product id.